# Is my default rails environment set to test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

Every time I run `rake db:migrate`I get the following error when I try to do anything else with rake:

```
(work)doctorly:job_app$ rake
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError: 

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

    bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:393:in `check_pending!'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:406:in `load_schema_if_pending!'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:412:in `block in     maintain_test_schema!'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:640:in `suppress_messages'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:417:in `method_missing'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:412:in `maintain_test_schema!'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_help.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/var/host/media/removable/SD Card/work/job_app/test/test_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/var/host/media/removable/SD Card/work/job_app/test/controllers/welcome_controller_test.rb:1:in   `require'
/var/host/media/removable/SD Card/work/job_app/test/controllers/welcome_controller_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `require'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `each'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `each'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:20:in `invoke_rake_task'
/home/doctorly/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run
```

and I continue to get this error until I run `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`. How do I fix this so I don't have to run the second migrate every single time I migrate?

Comment: What do you mean by "makes me run"?

Comment: If I run `rake` it gives me a ton of output and says that I need to run it, and will not let me rake until I do.

Comment: Alright, added the output to the original question so people can tell what is happening.

Comment: What does `echo $RAILS_ENV` output?

Comment: It doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my default rails environment set to test?

No, you're *asking* rails to run your tests.

When you run `rake` with no arguments, it runs the default task, which with Rails means running your tests. You need to set up your test environment to run them. If you don't to run your tests, don't run `rake`, give it an actual command.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the information, cleared things up instantly.